# How to make this call using Bloomberg API

Tags: c#, api, bloomberg, overriding

`=BDS("EJ9191945@BGN Corp";"DES_CASH_FLOW";"SETTLE_DT=20131113";"cols=3;rows=20")`

I use to get information on securities by Bloomberg API (Ref and Hist request) and everything would be fine, but here I faced such a problem: It is necessary to get a list of payments on the bond. There is a solution in the form Excel Add `=BDS("EJ9191945@BGN Corp";"DES_CASH_FLOW";"SETTLE_DT=20131113";"cols=3;rows=20")`.

How do I implement this formula using the Bloomberg API (ReferenceDataRequest or HistoricalDataRequest) ?

Comment: Try using code blocks to make your question easier to read, and please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That would be a ReferenceDataRequest - so just send such a request as you usually do it with the fields and overrides in your formula.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code example (in C#) to request the above field:

```
Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");

// securities
Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
securities.AppendValue("EJ9191945@BGN Corp");

// fields
Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
fields.AppendValue("DES_CASH_FLOW");

// overrides
Element overrides = request["overrides"];
Element override1 = overrides.AppendElement();
override1.SetElement("fieldId", "SETTLE_DT");
override1.SetElement("value", "20131113");

session.SendRequest(request, d_identity, null);
```

I hope this helps.